# PHP: get the value of TEXTBOX then pass it to a VARIABLE

Tags: php, variables, textbox, get, forum

Good Day!.

I need a kinda little help for PHP. I’m really really newbie for PHP and I already search it to google and can’t find any solution.

My Problem is:

I want to get the value of textbox1 then transfer it to another page where the value of textbox1 will be appeared in the textbox2.

Below is my codes for PHP:

```
<html>
<body>

<form name='form' method='post' action="testing2.php">

Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I also add the code below and the error is “Notice: Undefined index: name”

```
<?php 
$name = $_GET['name'];
echo $name;
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: Please include at-least portion of your code here. Giving links only is not accepted

Answer (score 1):

Your method is post, so use `$_POST`

Also, try wrapping it around an isset function:

```
 if (isset($_POST['name'])){
    echo $_POST['name'];
 }
```

This will also handle the undefined error

Answer (score 0):

This would be your textbox2:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox2" id="name" <?php echo (isset($_POST['name']) ? 'value=' .htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']). ' : ''); ?>/>
```

If you want to use the GET method, change post to get in your form and $_POST to $_GET in the php code of textbox2